# Генерация PDM сигнала на raspberry pico

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-pico, circuitpython

Возможно вопрос сформулирован недостаточно грамотно, но задача состоит в том, чтобы передать стороннему устройству сигнал вместо установленного на нем PDM микрофона.
к сожалению не смог найти какой либо информации на этот счет.

Еще раз: Есть устройство, на борту которого установлен DPM микрофон типа вот такого: https://www.adafruit.com/product/3492

Задача: убрать микрофон и на его контакты подать сигнал с pico, а если точнее взять mp3 файл и "передать" его так, как будто звук был записан микрофоном.